# Crash while importing localizations in Xcode: (group) should not be nil

Tags: xcode, xcode7, translation

I am trying to import localization files with Xcode and `xcodebuild`.

I get the following output from `xcodebuild -importLocalizations -project foo.xcodeproj -localizationPath ~/translations/foo/fi.xliff`:

```
2016-03-31 12:56:38.464 xcodebuild[8446:350058] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-10183.3/IDEFoundation/Localization/IDELocalizationWork.m:177
Details:  (group) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDELocalizationWork>
Method:   +groupStreamFromFileReference:language:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fde32605b30>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   __61+[IDELocalizationWork groupStreamFromFileReference:language:]_block_invoke_2.252 (in IDEFoundation)
  4   __33-[IDEStream(IDEStreamMonad) map:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
  5   __24-[_IDEStreamMap onNext:]_block_invoke_4 (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadOrderedUniquingWorkQueue _processWorkItemsWithDeadline:] (in DVTAbort trap: 6
```

I suspect this failure is what causes Xcode to crash as well. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was missing some translatable files from my project.

This issue was solved when I added `Localizable.strings` and its localizations, I also added `InfoPlist.strings` and its localizations, but I am not sure if it had anything to do with the problem.

I also had to add the missing files into the translated xliff-files, I suppose this was the missing `(group)` from the error message.

Comment: I'm having the same problem atm. What do you mean that you "add the missing files into the translated xliff-files"?

Comment: @Mikael I think I meant that the xliff xml contains `<file original="something.strings">...</file>` for all translatable files. My xliff was missing some. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After spending wayyyy to much time on this, I found out that apple released an update for Xcode (7.3.1) that will most likely resolve this issue for you (it did for me).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by [Xcode says Infoplist.strings already exists when I import localizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111016/xcode-says-infoplist-strings-already-exists-when-i-import-localizations).

After removing both a reference to InfoPlist.strings and the file itself from Xcode project, the crash described above didn't happen to me.