# Xcode says Infoplist.strings already exists when I import localizations

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have a Xcode project and I've added a language for localization. I exported the xliff file, added the translation and imported it back into Xcode. Everything works fine.

Then, at a later point, I've added new strings so I need to update the translation. I repeat the process but when I import the localization now I get the following error message:

> “InfoPlist.strings” couldn’t be moved to “nb.lproj” because an item
>   with the same name already exists.

The localization is not updated. Anyone know what's causing this? I tried to move `InfoPlist.strings` out of the nb.lproj directory but it didnt make any difference and no new `InfoPlist.strings` file was created.

Why cant Xcode just overwrite the file if it needs to be replaced?

Comment: You can refer this http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: You probably just deleted the reference from Xcode. Go to the actual location of the file that you want to delete. In other words the location in finder. If the file is still there then manually delete it.

Comment: I am facing same issue with xcode 9.2, I tried all things, like deleting plist files in xliff files, deleting .strings files from their physical location but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you already solved this, but I had the same problem; maybe this will help someone.

Ultimately, I used `find . -name "InfoPlist.strings"` in the workspace directory, and found that there were two other InfoPList.strings in addition to the one I had deleted.

Once I deleted them, my import worked again.

Answer (score -1):

You probably just deleted the reference from Xcode. Go to the actual location of the file that you want to delete. In other words the location in finder. If the file is still there then manually delete it.

I came across some weird behaviour with localisation files a while back where Xcode would not ask if I wanted to delete the file reference or send to trash, it would just 'delete'. Later found out it was only deleting the reference in Xcode.

Comment: No, I actually deleted the InfoPlist.strings file using the terminal so the file is certainly gone.